# angular smart-table, st-sort dynamic columns

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I use 2 tabs, the first work well but not the second. I have a problem to sort my data with smart table, the global search work well for both cases.

```
$scope.reports1 = [{fieldsName:['number1','number2','number3'],
                records:[{number1:10,number2:8,number3:40},
                         {number1:1,number2:4,number3:55},
                         {number1:8,number2:10,number3:35},
                         {number1:8,number2:11,number3:44}]}];


$scope.reports2 = [{fieldsName:['number1','number2','number3'],
                records:[{dyn_array:{number1:10,number2:8,number3:40}},
                         {dyn_array:{number1:1,number2:4,number3:55}},
                         {dyn_array:{number1:8,number2:10,number3:35}},
                         {dyn_array:{number1:8,number2:11,number3:44}}
                  ]}];
```

Here the plunk :http://plnkr.co/edit/AGQqugefnv4RzYTxH8ua?p=preview

My columns are dynamic, that's why I need to create a new dyn_array because I will use others static columns like ID that I don't want to show.

An idea ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: you can always use a lib like underscore or lodash to modify your data to what reports1 is like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response from  lorenzofox3 on github :
the problem is that your data structure does not match what you display
an item (row) is

```
{dyn_array:{number1:"foo",number2:"bar"}}
```

whereas you ask to sort by "number1" which is property that does not exist on your rows.

You have to specifically provide a getter function to tell orderBy filter on which nested property you want to sort.

see plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/ojbbZK?p=preview